# Visual Studio Code giving a schema.pbiviz.json "File not found" error message on automatically generated pbiviz.json file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am working through the [Power BI custom visual development tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/custom-visual-develop-tutorial) by Microsoft. I have followed the steps until the "Developing the visual elements" section and have managed to generate the standard Power BI visual template via the `pbiviz new visualNameHere` command. It successfully compiles and works on my sample report on Power BI .

However, before I have even changed anything beyond the tutorial steps, I get an error message in Visual Studio Code that something is wrong with the automatically generated pbiviz.json file.

The error given is:

```
File not found (<removed>\CircleCard\.api\v1.6.0\schema.pbiviz.json))
```

Since the visual does compile can I just ignore this message and assume that it is a Visual Studio quirk? I am confused as to what setting is even searching for this, and why is it searching under .api\v1.6.0\ when the current api version seems to be 2.6.0.

[image: File not found (....\CircleCard.api\v1.6.0\schema.pbiviz.json))]

Comment: Just wanted to add if someone else is doing the Circle Card tutorial, the pbiviz update changed quite a few things and some steps may need to be adjusted according to this documentation. https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-visuals/docs/how-to-guide/migrating-to-powerbi-visuals-tools-3-0/

Answer (score 2):

After seeing the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50009329/unable-to-open-filename-file-not-found-filewrong-file-path-filename) I decided to look at settings.json in the .vscode directory and found the source of all the incorrect api directories. I changed them to reference the api under ./node_modules/powerbi-visuals-api/.

That is to say in `.vscode\settings.json` I changed

```
    "json.schemas": [
    {
        "fileMatch": [
            "/pbiviz.json"
        ],            
        "url": "./.api/v1.6.0/schema.pbiviz.json"
    },
    {
        "fileMatch": [
            "/capabilities.json"
        ],            
        "url": "./.api/v1.6.0/schema.capabilities.json"
    },
    {
        "fileMatch": [
            "/dependencies.json"
        ],            
        "url": "./.api/v1.6.0/schema.dependencies.json"
    }        
]
```

to...

```
    "json.schemas": [
    {
        "fileMatch": [
            "/pbiviz.json"
        ],            
        "url": "./node_modules/powerbi-visuals-api/schema.pbiviz.json"
    },
    {
        "fileMatch": [
            "/capabilities.json"
        ],            
        "url": "./node_modules/powerbi-visuals-api/schema.capabilities.json"
    },
    {
        "fileMatch": [
            "/dependencies.json"
        ],            
        "url": "./node_modules/powerbi-visuals-api/schema.dependencies.json"
    }        
]
```

---

Edit: Also relevant is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56847580/3170135) explaining that an npm update causes the api folder generation to be different.